# You're in the same situation as me / mine

Tags: possessive-pronouns

Which one is correct?

> "You're in the same situation as me"

or

> "You're in the same situation as mine"

Example :

- My sister always annoys me, although I tell my parents to stop her, she keeps doing it.
- You're in the same situation as me / mine

Comment: Would you say 'You're in the same taxi as mine'?

Comment: Ah; the phantom upvoter; the DD.

Comment: Never heard the variant with "mine" before. Where have you come across it? It might be possible to argue it's grammatical as in parseable, but it is clearly not idiomatic at all. As Edwin demonstrates in his comment, you can use it for comedic effect, but that's about it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, I came across it here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5628242?tstart=0  "- Try with a genuine adapter (if you're in the same situation as mine, aka cheap $3 adapter)"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _The situation that you are in is the same as my situation. ==> The situation that you are in is the same as mine. ==> You're in the same situation as mine._ I haven't heard it this way either, but it's a logically valid question. And it doesn't work with the 'taxi' example very well, because ... well, some other reason.

Comment: Interesting. Looking at the Apple thread, the original author even uses this construction more than once. He begins by saying "I am in the same situation as yours". He uses other peculiar turns of phrase, too ("try with a genuine adapter"). And yet he doesn't appear to be a non-native speaker. It's safe to say that "same as me" is standard, and even "same as I" is common, but "same as mine" is very idiosyncratic and alien. Not sure what dialect that is. Might be worth investigating.

Comment: ***Yours is** the same situation as mine*. Even stretching things, I don't think it's possible to parse OP's version as "syntactically valid".

Comment: @RegDwigнt how about saying " that is the same situation as mine" instead of saying " you're in the same situation as mine "?

Comment: "That is the same situation as mine" is an entirely different construction. We'd be getting off-topic there. Let's not get distracted.

Comment: @RegDwigнt all right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *mine* is a possessive, it would need to be matched with a possessive when used in *same as*. You could use it if you wrote

> Your situation is the same as mine.

But if the element that *same as* refers to is a noun/pronoun, then you need to use a noun or pronoun as well to keep them consistent. So it should be

> You're in the same situation as me.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're in the same situation as me.

   - You are in the same situation again, as me. Why don't you try to change the role in that situation. Be as someone else except as me.
2. You're in the same situation as mine.

   - You're in the same situation as my situation. We have different situations, but yours is the same as mine.
3. You're in the same situation as I.

   - You are in the same situation as I am. You are in that situation as I am in that situation. We are sharing the same exact situation.