# The same as +object or possessive pronoun

Tags: grammar, adjectives

1. Tony has the same book **as I do** (He now has my very book).
2. Tony has the same book **as mine** (His book is a copy of my book,it
   has the same title,written by the same writer).
3. Tony's car is the **same as mine** (Our car are similar, they have a
   similar model, they are both Fiat 500, for example ).
4. Tony drives the **same car as me** (He is now driving my own car and
   not a different one).

I'd like to focus your attention on the pattern "same as". We all know that it could mean 1) similar to or 2) identical. My question was how can I understand whether it means "similar" or "identical"?
My hypothesis is:

- if the "as" is followed by a objective pronoun, it means "identical, exactly the thing mentioned and not another one".
- if the "as" is followed by a possessive pronoun (mine, yours, theirs,
  etc.), it means "of the same type, similar".

Comment: I don't think I agree with your premises. I could easily read "Tony drives the same car as me" to mean "Tony and I drive the same type of car".

Comment: Related: [You're in the same situation as me / mine](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311947/youre-in-the-same-situation-as-me-mine)

Comment: If you are asking about interpreting what you read or hear, then I'm afraid you often have to rely on context to make this distinction.  If you're asking about how to write, then I recommend avoiding such ambiguous constructions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntactical rule to determine this, you just have to get it from the context. For example, I would normally read all of your examples as referring to similar, but not identical, objects.

Other clues being absent, I think that ("similar, not identical") is the default position for most readings, even for something more direct like

> Tony and I learned from the same book.

...I would still say that means two copies of the same title. You need something like this to make it explicit:

> Tony and I learned from the same copy of the book.

---

*Update*: to answer @Peter's question, while what *follows* "the same as" seems to make no difference, actually there is one simple modification that helps, and that is to use "the ***very*** same" to indicate identity as opposed to similarity:

> Tony and I learned from the *very* same book.

Comment: Threfore it does not matter if "the same"is followed by "as I do" or by "as mine",the meaning depends on then context.Doesn't it ?